Water Heater leak from hot water line
EDITED:  Plumber came out and fixed the leak, and the color coding of the valve handles is misleading.  Despite them seeming to indicate cold coming in on the left, and hot going out on the right, it's reversed (and I guess it's normal that cold is usually on the right, hot on the left, don't know why previous homeowner/plumber/whoever did the valve handles opposite)
I noticed a leak from our water heater.  It appears to be coming from the hot water line coming out of it (on the right in the picture, where it goes into the wall; but the lines actually cross, though it goes into the right side of the wall its attached to the left on the water heater, which the manual confirms is the hot water output), not the water heater itself.
So I'm trying to shut it off in the meantime, without shutting of all water to the house until I can get someone to come out and look at it.   I have closed what appears to be the cold water intake as far as it will go.  The valve and line it's attached to are PVC/plastic so I'm afraid to apply too much force.
Also shut it off the circuit breaker.
But the hot water line is still leaking.  When I turn on hot water faucets, it's still flowing but greatly reduced.  I ran them for several minutes and don't understand how there is still water flowing.
Am I missing something here?  It's a Rheem model XE40M06ST45U1 if that matters)


It appears that neither the cold water into the heater nor the hot water out is turned off.  To be closed the valve should have the handles perpendicular to the line.

Ya, I should have been clearer, this picture was taken prior to me closing the inlet valve, which is now perpindicular, but I'm still getting a low flow to the faucets and the leak continues.

Does the hot water flow stop if you turn the red valve closed?

Huesmann you were on the right track... plumber came out and fixed the problem.  Turns out cold water line is on the right, output of hot water is on the left, despite the coloring of the valve handles seeming to indicate the reverse.

Go upstream to the next shutoff valve (it seems as though the local valves are leaking-by). The main cold water isolation valve to the house would be a good spot.
Also, you may be experiencing air lock wherein normal gravity-flow of liquid may be slowed or stopped; open a valve/tap to atmosphere at the highest point to ensure that lines are completely drained.
Your local ball valves are (relatively) reliable; however I have encountered some that leak-by, particularly plastic ones like yours (which usually have a rubber seal; rubber wears out).

on the picture neither valve is in close position. those are quarter. turn valves and the handle has to be perpendicular to the pipe. you can not force close more than that –
if it is still leaking before the valve then you have to empty the water heater to fix it. to do that you close the cold inlet into water heater and drain the thank.
